# Как достать мета данные у видео файлов?

Tags: c++, qt, metadata

Не получается таким образом вывести когда был создан файл:

```
                QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
                 player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(model->index(i,1).data().toString()));
                    connect(player, SIGNAL(metaDataChanged()), SLOT(playerMetaDataChanged()));
                    QString GPSLatitudeVideo = "";
                    QString GPSLongitudeVideo = "";
                    QDateTime DateTimeOriginalVideo;
                    qDebug()<<model->index(i,1).data().toString()<<"+++";
                    qDebug()<< Q_FUNC_INFO << "player->isMetaDataAvailable()" << player->isMetaDataAvailable();

                    if (player->isMetaDataAvailable())
                    {
                      GPSLatitudeVideo = player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::GPSLatitude).toString();
                      GPSLongitudeVideo = player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::GPSLongitude).toString();
                      DateTimeOriginalVideo = player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::Date).toDateTime();
                      qDebug()<< Q_FUNC_INFO << DateTimeOriginalVideo.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz");
                      qDebug()<< Q_FUNC_INFO << "+++"<<GPSLatitudeVideo<<GPSLongitudeVideo<<DateTimeOriginalVideo;
                    }

void MainWindow::playerMetaDataChanged()
{
    qDebug() << " ";
    qDebug() << "AvailableMetaData:";
    qDebug() << " ";
    QStringList metaData = player->availableMetaData();
    foreach (QString metaDataType, metaData) {
        qDebug() << "Type of metadata: " + metaDataType;
        qDebug() << player->metaData(metaDataType);
        qDebug() << "---------------";
    }
    qDebug() << " ";
}
```

Тут `model->index(i,1).data().toString()` - ссылка на файл. Как  мне вывести `QMediaMetaData::Date`? Дату создания файла.

Мета данные у файла ffmpeg :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя функция playerMetaDataChanged выводит

```
AvailableMetaData:

"Type of metadata: AudioBitRate"
QVariant(uint, 253632)
---------------
"Type of metadata: AudioCodec"
QVariant(QString, "MPEG AAC Audio")
---------------
"Type of metadata: ChannelCount"
QVariant(uint, 2)
---------------
"Type of metadata: Duration"
QVariant(qlonglong, 12961)
---------------
"Type of metadata: PixelAspectRatio"
QVariant(QSize, QSize(1, 1))
---------------
"Type of metadata: Resolution"
QVariant(QSize, QSize(3840, 2160))
---------------
"Type of metadata: SampleRate"
QVariant(uint, 48000)
---------------
"Type of metadata: VideoBitRate"
QVariant(uint, 61624760)
---------------
"Type of metadata: VideoCodec"
QVariant(QString, "H.264 Video")
---------------
"Type of metadata: VideoFrameRate"
QVariant(double, 25)
---------------
```

Тут нет даты создания.

Comment: дату создания (изменения) файла или дату записи видео?

Comment: и да, что код выше выводит? и какой вывод требуется? метаданные в файле действительно есть?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да мета данные в файле есть. Дату записи видео. Выводит :"J://Сб_апр_21_2018_21_45_56/split.avi" +++
void __cdecl MainWindow::SaveFiles(void) player->isMetaDataAvailable() false
void __cdecl MainWindow::SaveFiles(void) ""
void __cdecl MainWindow::SaveFiles(void) +++ "" "" QDateTime(Invalid)

Comment: первое предположение, судя по API — он не прогрузил метаданные к этому моменту и надо дождаться сигнала `metaDataChanged ()` и только потом всё грузить, но я бы сначала это проверил.... (Нулевое предположение — одна из черепашек пи... врёт... и метаданных как Qt  и говорит нет.)

Comment: @Fat-Zer Можно написать пример .

Comment: может как-нибудь попозже, если не забуду... пока до экспериментов руки не доходят...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, похоже, всё-таки забыли.

Comment: @Arhad, да нет, то что я хотел предложить уже добавлено в вопрос и вроде как работает... а то что именно даты нет я объяснить не могу... рабочая версия — этот атрибут не поддерживается конкретным бекэндом, но у себя пока не проверял...

Comment: посмотрел у себя — похоже в `gstreamer`'е время создания поддерживается только при захвате с камеры, на вскидку в `directshow` и `wmf` (хз, что там в win используется) всё должно работать и для видео...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я не совсем понял что смотреть ... У меня не отображается время создание видео .

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, я, честно, сказать не могу, что смотреть... скорей всего на win платформе (для vista+) Qt будет использовать wmf в качестве бекэнда... в исходниках в `src/plugins/wmf/player/mfmetadatacontrol.cpp` он вроде бы какую-то дату загружает, но сказать с уверенностью, что это именно так я не могу, а, если верить твоим экспериментам, это не работает... в gstreamer-плагине на linux дата явно фигурирует только для получния видео с камеры... так что я бы сказал, что *импорт даты съёмки из файла в Qt не реализован*… (хотя с полной уверенностью могу утверждать это только для linux/gstreamer)